# Problema para conectar com oracle usando o php 7.1?

Tags: php, oracle

Pessoal estou com um problema para fazer uma conexão com o Oracle no PHP 7 aparece a mensagem de erro abaixo:

```php
ERROR: could not find driverERROR: could not find driver 
  Notice: Undefined variable: conAD in C:\laragon\www\systemag\area_restritaAG.php on line 59

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
 in C:\laragon\www\systemag\area_restritaAG.php:59 Stack trace: 
    #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\systemag\area_restritaAG.php on line 59
```

Segue os códigos que tentei fazer abaixo:

```php
try {
    $conAG = new PDO('oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/xe/ORCL', 'core_11_1', 'T3cn1c05p');
    $conAG->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $conAD = new PDO('oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/xe/ORCL', 'wms_eadi', 'wms_eadi');
    $conAD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//$db_connectAG = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.20.220.43)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=alcisagprd)))';
//$db_userAG = 'core_11_1';
//$db_passAG = 'T3cn1c05p';
//$db = "oci:dbname=alcisagprd";
//$conAG = oci_connect($db_user,$db_pass,$db_connectAG,'AL32UTF8');


//$conAG = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$db_connectAG,$db_userAG,$db_passAG);

//$db_connectAD = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.20.220.32)(PORT=1522)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ALCISSTB)))';
//$db_userAD = 'wms_eadi';
//$db_passAD = 'wms_eadi';
//$conAD = oci_pconnect($db_userAD,$db_passAD,$db_connectAD,'AL32UTF8'); 
//$conAD = oci_connect("wms_eadi","wms_eadi","ALCIS_NEW"); conexão alternativa 
//$conAG = oci_connect('core_11_1', 'T3cn1c05p', 'ALCISAGPRD','AL32UTF8');


//$AD = oci_parse($conAD,"select k.suchbegriff from KLIENTEN k where (k.suchbegriff = '".$cnpj."' or k.suchbegriff = '".$tb_cnpj."')");
//oci_execute($AD);
//$lineAD = oci_fetch_all($AD, $res);

$AD = $conAD->query("select k.suchbegriff from KLIENTEN k where (k.suchbegriff = '".$cnpj."' or k.suchbegriff = '".$tb_cnpj."')");
$AD->execute();
$lineAD = $AD->rowCount();

$AG = $conAG->query("select k.suchbegriff from KLIENTEN k where (k.suchbegriff = '".$cnpj."' or k.suchbegriff = '".$tb_cnpj."')");
$AG->execute();
$lineAG = $AD->rowCount();

//$AG = oci_parse($conAG,"select k.suchbegriff from KLIENTEN k where (k.suchbegriff = '".$cnpj."' or k.suchbegriff = '".$tb_cnpj."')");
//oci_execute($AG);
//$lineAG = oci_fetch_all($AG, $res);

if($lineAD > 0 && $lineAG > 0){
    header("Location: clientes/indexFull.php");
}else if($lineAD > 0 && $lineAG == 0){
    header("Location: clientes/index.php");
}else if($lineAG > 0 && $lineAD == 0){
    header("Location: clienteAG/indexAG.php");
}else{
    echo "<script>
            alert('CNPJ NÃO SE ENCONTRADO NA BASE DADOS\\nFAVOR ENTRAR EM CONTATO COM ATENDIMENTO');
            location.href='formulario_cadastroTeste.php';
            </script>";
}
```

Estou utilizando o Laragon e já habilitei as extensões do **oci8_12c**, **oci8_11g** e **oci8** esses dois últimos baixei no [deste link](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0/windows)

Já verifiquei o **php.ini** e as linhas com as tais extensões estão descomentadas.

já restartei o Laragon com os serviços já reiniciei o servidor, ainda não consigo fazer a conexão alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Windows ou Linux? Reiniciou o servidor? [O Instant Client está instalado](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html)? Por que deu erro para `conAD` e `conAG` não?

Comment: é um Windows Server 2016 sim reiniciei, não instalei o Instant Client vou instalar aqui.

Comment: Instalei o Instant Client e sobre o erro esta dando nos dois que eu mandei só uma mensagem de erro não a outra. porém mesmo instalando não funcionou

Comment: Eu sei que não é o seu objetivo tenta uma conexão via ODBC. Só para descartar a possibilidade do problema ser com a fonte de dados.